# 音声が再生されません

Tags: swift

先日、音声再生のプログラムを記述したのですが、音声が再生されません。ご指摘の程、よろしくお願いします。

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player:AVAudioPlayer?

    let sound_data = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample", ofType: "mp3")!)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        do {
            let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound_data)
            player.play()
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }

        player?.prepareToPlay()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func play(sender: UIButton) {
        player?.play()
    }

    @IBAction func pause(sender: UIButton) {
        player?.pause()
    }

    @IBAction func stop(sender: UIButton) {
        player?.stop()
        player?.currentTime = 0

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

mp3を再生するためにAVAudioPlayerのインスタンスを生成してますが、それがどこにも参照されないまま解放されてるのが原因かと思われます。

以下のように修正してはどうでしょうか？

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    do {
        // ローカル変数に格納していたのを修正
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound_data)
        player?.play()
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

    player?.prepareToPlay()
}
```

Comment: ご回答通りに変更しましたら、音声が再生されました。
ご丁寧にありがとうございます！